# MVC JQuery DatePicker not working in ie (works in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I am trying to use the basic JQuery DatePicker (calendar) and Time Control.  It works perfectly in Chrome, but in IE it just gives me text boxes.

VIEW:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STARTDATE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.STARTDATE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STARTDATE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.STARTTIME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.STARTTIME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.STARTTIME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

MODEL:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime? STARTDATE { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:H:mm}")]
    [Display(Name = "Time")]
    public DateTime? STARTTIME { get; set; }
```

Comment: I cannot see where you are using the Jquery DatePicker\TimeControl. Which plugin are you using?Jqueryui?

Comment: var jQueryBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery");jQueryBundle.Include("~/assets/js/jquery.min.js");

Comment: The HTML-5 datepicker (`input type="date"`) is only supported in Chrome and Edge. (refer [comparison site](https://html5test.com/compare/browser/chrome-44/firefox-40/ie-11/ie-Edge%2013.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're neither using JqueryUI nor other plugins. So I assume that the DatePicker you're seeing is just the one rendered by default by Chrome for date input.

As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) it's just supported by Chrome, Opera and partially by iOS Safari.
For this reason I suggest you to use a plugin like [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) in order to show the datepicker.

There is a full sample in the [asp.net documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4) that shows how to integrate it in MVC5.